# Specify end of record (EOL) delimiter while importing from a text file?

Tags: r

I'm trying to import into R a large number of pipe-delimited files that were created in a windows environment, with CR+LF as the end of record (=EOL) delimiter.  However, they also have CR's scattered about periodically, which is resulting in frequent inappropriately-split lines.  Ideally, want an efficient way to solve this problem from within R - either by finding a way to specify the EOL delimiter when I import, or, if necessary, by reading in the text file and excising the CRs before any parsing of lines is done.

The creators of the files comment on this problem and recommend adding "TERMSTR= CRLF" into your SAS code, and I can find lots of discussions of how to do this in other languages as well.  For R, however, all I can find is this discussion, here on stackoverflow:

[Possible to change the record delimiter in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115887/possible-to-change-the-record-delimiter-in-r)

The sample problem given is a great match for my problem.  The solution identified is nice for their specific situation of having a single file like this, but for me would require coding up separate scripts for importing each of the dozens of files, since each have different primary keys that would need to be recognized after the fact to repair the inappropriate import.  Alternatively, I could open each file in something like Notebook++ to remove the extra CR's but again, that seems quite inefficient, and then would have to be repeated by hand every time the initial data set was updated by its producers.

Given how frequent a problem this seems to be for people, and the existence of hard-coded solutions in other programming languages, I'm confused as to why there isn't a fix in R and feel like I must be missing something.  It seems clear (I think?) that there's no way to do this directly from read.table or even from readLines, but is there a way perhaps to do this using scan, that I'm missing?

Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: If we code this, it won't solve the problem. Castrate the create of the crappy formatted file first, then, we'll talk.

Comment: Ha.  The thing is, though, it's actually pretty high-quality data, as these things go - it's the professionally curated data from clinical trials.gov: http://www.ctti-clinicaltrials.org/what-we-do/analysis-dissemination/state-clinical-trials/aact-database